# Why NodeJS domains documentation code tries to terminate the process?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, node.js-domains

In the official NodeJS documentation there is code example where process tries to exit gracefully when there was exception in domain (it closes connections, waits for some time for other requests and then exits).

But why just not send the 500 error and continue to work?

In my application I want to throw some **expected** Errors (like FrontEndUserError) when user input is not valid, and catch these exceptions somewhere in middleware to send pretty error message to client. With domains it very easy to implement, but are there any pitfalls around this?

```
app.use (err, req, res, next) ->
  if err instanceof FrontEndUserError
    res.send {error: true, message: err.message}
  else
    log err.trace
    res.send 500
```

Answer (score 1):

From [domain](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html#domain_warning_don_t_ignore_errors) module official documentation:

> By the very nature of how **throw** works in JavaScript, there is almost never any way to safely "pick up where you left off", without leaking references, or creating some other sort of undefined brittle state.
>
> The safest way to respond to a thrown error is to shut down the process ...

To me that means when something thrown an error in your NodeJS application, then you're done unfortunately. If you do care about how your application works and the result is important to you, then your best bet is to kill the process and start it again. However, in that last milliseconds, you can be more nice to other clients, let them finish their work, say sorry to new clients, log couple of things if you want and then kill the process and start it again.

That's what exactly happening in the NodeJS domain module's documentation example.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your web application/server as a state machine.

Unless your application is very small, it is very unlikely that you happen to know every state  that your machine can possibly be in.
When you get an error, you have two choices:

1) Examine the error and decide what to do, or

2) ignore it.

In the first case, you gracefully change from one state to another. In the second case, you don't have any clue what state your machine is in, since you didn't bother seeing what the error was. Essentially, your machine's state is now 'undefined'.

It is for this reason, NodeJS recommends killing the process if an error propagates all the way to the event loop. Then again, this level of absolution may be overkill for pet projects and small apps, so your solution is quite fine too.

But imagine if you were writing a banking software; someday you get an error you've never seen before, you app simple ignores it and sends a 500; but each time someone is losing a 100k$. Here, I would want to make sure no error ever reaches the event loop, and if it does, kill the process with a detailed stack trace for later analysis.

Comment: Ok, but I can log trace before sending 500 (code example updated) for later analysis. So as I understood well, the only bad thing is some resources won't be released?

Comment: "NodeJS recommends killing the process if an error propagates all the way to the event loop" - could you provide reference please?

Comment: "The safest way to respond to a thrown error is to shut down the process." Under "Warning: Don't ignore errors!" in the domain documentation.
While domain and try/catch may seem to do the same things, remember with domains, you have more control over what component is part of the domain, as well as being able to bind a specific operation to a domain different from its parent domain.