# nodejs using cluster.setupMaster, send an object as argv

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing

I've have just dived into NodeJS and I'm reading on taking advantage of all CPU's cores and spawning the process among all the available resources.

It seems like a pretty interesting topic, and I'm testing it right now. But I have a question concerning the `argv` object key in the cluster settings.

I'm starting the server by using this script :

```
var path = require("path"),
    colors = require("colors");

var cluster = require('cluster'),
    os = require('os'),
    cores = os.cpus();

/*

var config = require(path.join(__dirname, 'config.json'));

*/

/*
 * Start Server
*/

cluster.setupMaster({

    exec : path.join(__dirname, "application.js"),
    args : ["--environment", "dev"]
});

if (cluster.isMaster) {

    for (var i = cores.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        cluster.fork();
    };

    cluster.on("fork", function(worker) {

        console.log("Worker : [ %d ][ Status : Forking ]".cyan, worker.process.pid);
    });

    cluster.on("online", function(worker) {

        console.log("Worker : [ %d ][ Status : Online ]".green, worker.process.pid);
    });

    cluster.on("listening", function(worker, address) {

        console.log("Worker : [ %d ][ Status : Listening ][ Address : %s ][ Port : %d ]".yellow, worker.process.pid, address.address, address.port);
    });

    cluster.on("disconnect", function(worker) {

        console.log("Worker : [ %d ][ Status : Disconnected ]".white, worker.process.pid);
    });


    /*
     * Restart Dead Workers
    */

    cluster.on("exit", function(worker, code, signal) {

        console.log("Worker : [ %d ][ Status : Exit ][ Signal : %s ][ Code : %s ]".red, worker.process.pid, signal, code);

        cluster.fork();
    });

} else {

};
```

The above would be my `server.js`, which when run, as stated in the `exec`, starts off the application :

```
var express = require("express"),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require("path"),
    optimist = require("optimist"),
    colors = require("colors"),
    recess = require("recess");

var application = module.exports = express(),
    config = optimist.argv;

console.log(config);

var routes = require(path.join(__dirname, "routes")),
    api = require(path.join(__dirname, "routes", "api"));

application.set('view engine', 'jade');
application.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

application.configure(function(){

    application.use(express.bodyParser());
    application.use(express.methodOverride());

    application.use("/assets", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

    application.use(express.logger('dev'));

    application.use(application.router);
});

application.configure('development', function(){

    application.use(express.errorHandler({

        dumpExceptions: true,
        showStack: true
    }));
});

application.configure('production', function(){

    application.use(express.errorHandler());
});


/*
 * JSON API
*/

application.get('/api/test', api.test);


/*
 * Routing
*/

application.get('/', routes.index);
application.get('/partials/:name', routes.partials);

application.get('*', routes.index);

/*
 * Start Server
*/

var server = http.createServer(application).listen(process.env.PORT);
```

So firstly, can I use `argv` to send an object as options to the `application.js` script ? If so how ? If not I guess I can only send simple options as I'm doing right now.

Secondly, and lastly, am I doing the syntax right ? Is it necessary to have something else in the `if(cluster.isMaster) {} else {}` ( I'm most interested in if there's anything needed in the `else` ) ? I'm sorry if the question seems a bit stupid, but I've just started a few days ago and I'm pretty eager to learn more about Node :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can send objects to the child:

1. By serializing the object into a JSON string and passing to argv (which only takes string arguments) and deserializing at the worker, and
2. Listening for the worker's `online` event on Master, and then sending an object using `cluster.worker[<id>].send(<object>)` which will automatically take care of (de)serialization.

You master looks fine. About the only improvement I can suggest is wrapping your workers in `domain` for better error handling.

Comment: I see, but using `cluster.worker[<id>].send(<object>)` won't that happen about as many times as cores I have ( or the server does ) ? Or that is exactly the purpose ? What do you mean wrapping my workers in `domain` ?

Comment: That is the purpose. For `domain`s, check http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.11.2/api/domain.html


If you want to send the object to only certain workers, then keep a reference to the worker id from the return value of the `fork` call.  Then use that id to check if the worker that just initialized is the one that you want to send the message to.

Comment: Could you give an example of how I could wrap my workers ? That would be more specific to my case. I've read the doc on domains, but it seemed pretty vague when it showed the example with the routing, does it mean that depending on the route we have a different behaviour ?

Comment: There are some complex use cases for domains, but the most basic version just wraps the entire worker, and if it catches any error, gracefully kills the worker to let the master recreate it (continuing past an error is very very bad: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770103/why-nodejs-domains-documentation-code-tries-to-terminate-the-process/16770331#16770331).

Check my WIP project (https://github.com/prajwalkman/vigil/blob/master/src/overseer.litcoffee) for an example, where I wrap each new worker in a domain.

Comment: Do you have a vanilla js example ? It's hard to read the coffee syntax since I never tried it :)

Comment: Sorry, not at the moment. I'll keep an eye out for it. Check this out though (http://prajwalkman.github.io/vigil/workers.html), it may be easier to understand.